# Enviar datos de un formulario

Tags: php, javascript, html5, php7

Tengo un formulario hecho con html y tengo la validación con un archivo.js externo por ende ya guardo en un array los valores de los inputs y  el textarea del formulario, es posible que se use una función para enviar datos que este escrita en php pero que a la vez se la pueda llamar dentro de una función javascript en este caso.

A continuación dejo el código que tengo dentro de la función mencionada anteriormente:

```
formulario.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(campos.nombre && campos.apellido && campos.telefono && campos.correo && campos.msj){
    enviarContacto();/// de prueba
    formulario.reset();
    document.getElementById('form-mensaje-exito').style.display="block";
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('form-mensaje-exito').style.display="none";
    },5000);
  }else{
    document.getElementById('form-mensaje').style.display="flex";
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('form-mensaje').style.display="none";
    },5000);
  }
});
```

La idea que tengo e imagino seria:

[image: idealización de archivo.js]

Es posible hacer esto y/o que me recomiendan.

Comment: Hay un tema conceptual en el planteo para que tengas en cuenta. Javascript corre en el puesto cliente, igual que el html. Y php corre en el servidor.
Entonces ejecutar una función desde javascript en php es como buscar ir del cliente al servidor, lo cual resulta incompatible a menos que utilices ajax. Ajax es un método que toma lo que ocurre en el cliente, lo traslada al server, lo procesa y luego lo devuelve para que el cliente siga su operación.

Comment: gracias por el dato Claudio